# Problemas Elementos/Imagens no Selenium Django

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver

Estou tendo algum problema de elementos **não carregarem** corretamente na página do `ChromeDriver` usando o selenium em minha aplicação Django.

Eu abanonei a ferramenta de testes do Django pois no meu cenário, preciso de toda a base carregada. E fazer um load fixtures seria muito demorado para iniciar os testes. Então eu uso uma base clonada de produção, tudo o que eu crio eu deleto no final dos testes (e deleto antes também caso de algum erro no script).

O script funciona perfeitamente, ele pega cada elemento certo, porém visualmente é horrivel. Alguns elementos ficam pretos, a maioria (se não todos) os textos somem (ficam invisiveis), etc. Não consigo ver várias ações visualmente no ChromeDriver que ele abre por conta disso.

Pesquisei bastante e não vi ninguem com esse problema. Eu também não estava, pois usava os testes do próprio Django.

O que fiz foi criar um novo **command** no Django para continuar tendo acesso aos models, executando o chrome normalmente.

Ele não dá nenhum erro, apenas a janela do navegador que abre, fica com os elementos não carregados perfeitamente.

**Versões**

```
ChromeDriver: 2.40
selenium==3.13.0
Django 2.0
```

**Meu código**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.add_argument("--kiosk")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(settings.BASE_DIR + '/chromedriver', chrome_options=chromeOptions)

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Comando de testes'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        browser.get('https://pt.stackoverflow.com/')
        ...
```

#### update

Estou inserindo uma imagem e adicionando recompensa para obter algum feedback. O problema persiste. Tentei atualizar versão do chromedrive, do selenium, etc. Acredito que o problema está relacionado ao selenium estar rodando em um Command do Python.

Como podem ver na imagem abaixo, os botões (azul e cinza) **não** estão aparecendo seus textos, os 2 selects não estão aparecendo os valores, as imagens estão com um fundo preto assim como todas as imagens do site (Tirei um print apenas de um pedaço por questão de sigilo mesmo).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]